# How to enumerate raw resources?

Tags: android

I have a number of files stored under `res/raw`. E.g.:

```
yeh_vidhi_mangal.txt  
om_jai_mahavir.txt  
tumse_laagi_lagan.txt
```

I would like to iterate over these files in code. Something like:

```
Resources myResources = getResources();
for(int i = 0; i < ...;i++)
{
   int id_of_ith_resource = ....
    InputStream in = myResources.openRawResource(id_of_ith_resource);
   // do my stuff
}
```

How to fill in the dots (`...`) above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you place your files into `assets` directory instead of the `raw` directory you can then use `AssetManager.list()` method to enumerate them. Not sure why you need them in `raw` directory as opposed to `assets` directory.

Comment: One example would be to start use the Network security config (https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html) where you would need to declare the certificates in the manifest (needs to be raw).
But as this feature is not available on all API versions you would also need to iterate over trusted CA anchors programmatically. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52691058/how-to-add-android-network-security-config-for-api-less-than-24

Answer (score 0):

if your raw folder contain static files only means, files does not  generate dynamically then use this method,

```
int num[] = {R.raw.yeh_vidhi_manga,R.raw.om_jai_mahavir,R.raw.tumse_laagi_lagan};

for(int resId in num){

InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(resId);
//do the stuff
}
```

else if content are generated dynamically from remote folder then use `AssetManager` and for iterate file `AssetManager.list();`