# Code to get JSON from server causes crash when run in android version 9

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

The following piece of code runs successfully if the android version is 6 or 7 but crashes for android version 9

```
public class TestConnectionToServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

String IPConnection ="http://************";

public String doInBackground(String... IntegerParam) {
    try {               
        URL url = new URL(IPConnection+"TestConnectionToServer");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        try {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));    
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }

            bufferedReader.close();         
            return stringBuilder.toString();                
        }                   
        finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }       
    catch(Exception e) {        
        Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
        return e.getMessage();     
    }   
}
```

Comment: "It crashes": Please provide more info what exactly does not work.

Answer (score 0):

One network related change with Android 9 is that it's no longer easy to use **http** instead of **https**, see [Protecting users with TLS by default in Android P](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/04/protecting-users-with-tls-by-default-in.html).

Most likely you can just switch to **https**.

If you want to/ have to stay with **http**, you have to change your app's network security config.

- Create a resource directory named *xml* in the *main/res* folder
- Create an XML resource file *mynetworksecurityconfig.xml* in this directory
- To allow insecure cleartext connections to a specific domain, you can declare the network security configuration as follows:

*mynetworksecurityconfig.xml*

```
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">insecure.example.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

- Finally, add a link to the config file in the app's `Manifest.xml` by setting the `android:networkSecurityConfig` attribute in the `application` tag

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.mynetworksecurityconfigtest">

    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/mynetworksecurityconfig"
                ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

See the training unit on [Network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) for more information.

Comment: when replace HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();          TO                                                                         HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection(); Get ERROR com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection

Comment: Did you change the prefix in `String IPConnection = ...` from http to https?

Comment: Yes ... but get another error     Hostname  ****   not verified certificate

Comment: Then it looks like you have to use http. See the two links for examples how to set up your network security configuration

Comment: is this [network security configuration] for device or in my app code java ????????? Thanks advance

Comment: @Hany Gaber - The configuration is part of your app's code and will be valid only for your app. Please see my edited answer, I tried to sketch what you have to do

Comment: many thanks for your effort ... this configuration require which minimum API version ?? note .. I user eclipse tools

Comment: @Hany Gaber - they say in the linked blog post that they added the network security config feature in Nougat. So that's what I'd try. About using Eclipse on the other hand... well, it is not the recommended IDE for Android so I suppose it's "use at your own peril" ;-)

Comment: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'networkSecurityConfig' in package 'android'

Comment: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'networkSecurityConfig' in package 'android'     is there any solution ??????     note I update SDK to API 28

Comment: @Hany Gaber - sorry but I can't reproduce your situation. I just tested again with an app with minSDK 19 and compileSDK = target SDK = 28. Once I used explicitly the build tools version 27.0.3, once I let Android Studio use the default build tools version (gradle version 3.1.3). Support lib version was always "28.0.0". The only thing I had to add because of the low minSDK was `tools:targetApi="24"`in the application tag of the Manifest.  See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52691058/5015207) on supporting lower android versions. My sample compiles and runs on Kitkat and on Oreo

Comment: @Hany Gaber - if you keep running into problems I think it's best if you ask a new question with an [MCVE] of your current approach. Comments are not really a good format for remote debugging