# API 19: Cleartext communication not permitted by network security policy

Tags: android

I have a public API that I have to use in the app. The API doesn't provide a `https`, so I would like to allow Cleartext access.

However I'm still supporting KitKat (API 19).

Therefore this solution `<application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">` leads to the error:

`Attribute networkSecurityConfig is only used in API level 24 and higher (current min is 19)`

So what do I do in this case?

**network_security_config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://....com/json/</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: Thats probably a Lint warning just add `tools:targetApi="n"` it will go away .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add Android Network Security Config for API less than 24](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52691058/how-to-add-android-network-security-config-for-api-less-than-24)

Comment: Ah yes, seems like a lint issue after all. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set another attribute: 
<application `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">`

Comment: Same problem. `Attribute usesCleartextTraffic is only used in API level 23 and higher (current min is 19)`